# Struggling to remove an item From List<T>,Though I have an Items in List<T>

Tags: asp.net, .net

I was trying to add item in `List< >` when User Click On the `AddToCart` Button. And finally I was trying to Remove an item from `List< >` when user click on `RemoveFromCart` Button. Finally, I was struggling to remove the item from `List< >`. Can anybody Please help me.

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
    int inc;
    protected void listview1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Buy")
        {
            int PC = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            Response.Redirect("~/Buy.aspx?PC=" + PC);
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
        {

            list1.Add(int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
                foreach (int i in list1)
                {
                    lbl.Text += i.ToString() + ",";
                    string length = lbl.Text.Length.ToString();
                    string sval = lbl.Text.Remove(int.Parse(length) - 1, 1);
                    lbl1.Text = sval.ToString();
                }           

            e.Item.FindControl("btnRemoveFromCart").Visible = true;
            inc = (int)ViewState["Increment"];
            ViewState["Increment"] = inc;
            inc += 1;
            lblitemscount.Text = inc.ToString();
            ViewState["Increment"] = inc;
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "RemoveFromCart")
        {
            int val = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            inc = (int)ViewState["Increment"];
            ViewState["Increment"] = inc;
            inc -= 1;
            lblitemscount.Text = inc.ToString();
            ViewState["Increment"] = inc;
            foreach (int j in list1)
            {
                if (list1.Contains(val))
                {
                    list1.Remove(val);
                }
                lbl1.Text += j.ToString();
            }
            e.Item.FindControl("btnRemoveFromCart").Visible = false;
        }
    }
}


----------
```

Comment: where do you populate list1?  Probably in some if !postback block I guess, so list1 is empty?

Comment: i was adding items into list1 ,when user click on the button having a command name called "AddToCart" in my code.so,there i was populating all the items @Mike Miller

Comment: Dynamically,I will be adding items in list1. so, not possibly to keep in !postback @MikeMiller

Comment: yeah but list1 will be blanked on the round trip of the button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove an item from a list whilst you're iterating through it.  You'll need to find the index of that item, then use the `RemoveAt` method to remove it from the list.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But the iteration is pointless, List.Remove will just remove the item/s that it thinks are equivalent.

Comment: yes ,it can remove an ,which is equivalent to the passed item into Remove() method.So only,here i was passing the value ,which is already available in list1.@Tom

Comment: Then how can I remove the item from a List .can you please tell me @Tom

Comment: @DineshMudaliyar Use `FindIndex` to get the index, then pass that index to `RemoveAt`.  It's been a long time since I've done WebForms so there may be some merit to what @MikeMiller is saying in regards to your list being empty.